# Adding Twilio account to a whatsapp group

Tags: python, api, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am currently developing an application which requires my twilio account to work in a whatsapp group chat to send and receive some messages. But when I try to add the twilio account to the group chat, it says, its not possible. So my question is, is this really impossible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

> Can I send messages to WhatsApp groups or manage groups?
>
> Currently, our API does not support messaging with or managing
> WhatsApp groups. We expect to add support for groups in the future.

Source: [Twilio API for WhatsApp Best Practices and FAQs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs)

Twilio has a product called Conversations, where you can add WhatsApp users to a conversation.

[Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/conversations)